# how to mock an exception call in python?

Tags: python, mocking

I have a code like this:

```
def extract(data):
    if len(data) == 3:
       a = 3
    else:
        component = data.split("-")
        if len(component) == 3:
            a,b,c = component
        else:
            raise globals.myException("data1", "Incorrect format", data)

    return a,b,c
```

This is a simplified one. I want to mock the exception class globals.myException. I'm doing that:

```
def test_extract_data_throws_exception(self):
        with patch('globals.myException') as mock: 
            mock.__init__("data1", "Incorrect format", "")
            with self.assertRaises(myException):
                self.assertEqual(extract(""), (""))
```

And I always get the error: "TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not MagicMock"

**EDIT**: As @Aaron Digulla suggest, monkey patching is the correct solution. I post the solution to help others.

```
def test_extract_data_throws_exception(self):
        #monkey patching
        class ReplaceClass(myException):
            def __init__(self, module, message, detail = u''):
                pass

        globals.myException = ReplaceClass
        with self.assertRaises(myException:
            self.assertEqual(extract(""), (""))
```

Comment: Why do you want to mock the exception? Why not simply throw it and catch it in the test?

Comment: MyException extends from Exception but adding some funcionality as Log services and other things. I know that I could include my exception as part of my test but I'd like to keep clean my unit test. Also, it is a matter of curiosity :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is `raise` checks the type of the argument. It must be a string (a.k.a "old style exceptions") or derived from `BaseException`

Since a mock isn't either, `raise` refuses to use it.

In this specific case, you either have to raise the exception or use [monkey patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765222/monkey-patch-python-class) (= overwrite the symbol `globals.myException` in your test and restore it afterwards).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've posted the solution using monkey patching.

Comment: You need to restore the original value after the test!