# Monkey patching a class in another module in Python

Tags: python, class, unit-testing, monkeypatching

I'm working with a module written by someone else. I'd like to monkey patch the `__init__` method of a class defined in the module. The examples I have found showing how to do this have all assumed I'd be calling the class myself (e.g. [Monkey-patch Python class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765222/monkey-patch-python-class)). However, this is not the case. In my case the class is initalised within a function in another module. See the (greatly simplified) example below:

**thirdpartymodule_a.py**

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 42
    def show(self):
        print self.a
```

**thirdpartymodule_b.py**

```
import thirdpartymodule_a
def dosomething():
    sc = thirdpartymodule_a.SomeClass()
    sc.show()
```

**mymodule.py**

```
import thirdpartymodule_b
thirdpartymodule_b.dosomething()
```

Is there any way to modify the `__init__` method of `SomeClass` so that when `dosomething` is called from mymodule.py it, for example, prints 43 instead of 42? Ideally I'd be able to wrap the existing method.

I can't change the thirdpartymodule*.py files, as other scripts depend on the existing functionality. I'd rather not have to create my own copy of the module, as the change I need to make is very simple.

**Edit 2013-10-24**

I overlooked a small but important detail in the example above. `SomeClass` is imported by `thirdpartymodule_b` like this: `from thirdpartymodule_a import SomeClass`.

To do the patch suggested by F.J I need to replace the copy in `thirdpartymodule_b`, rather than `thirdpartymodule_a`. e.g. `thirdpartymodule_b.SomeClass.__init__ = new_init`.

Comment: I don't see why it would make a difference where you're calling the class from.

Comment: Filenames should be `thirdpartymodule_a.py`, `thirdpartymodule_b.py`.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import thirdpartymodule_a
import thirdpartymodule_b

def new_init(self):
    self.a = 43

thirdpartymodule_a.SomeClass.__init__ = new_init

thirdpartymodule_b.dosomething()
```

If you want the new init to call the old init replace the `new_init()` definition with the following:

```
old_init = thirdpartymodule_a.SomeClass.__init__
def new_init(self, *k, **kw):
    old_init(self, *k, **kw)
    self.a = 43
```

Comment: Maybe you should include a call to the old `__init__`.

Comment: Seems like inheriting from `SomeClass` and replacing the class would be much more elegant than messing with the `__init__` functions themselves.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart You are probably right but I don't think the OP really wants to replace 42 by 43 in his own code. He specifically asked about monkey-patching though

Comment: Does this not create an infinite recursion if the new_init calls the old_init ? Because then new_init is assigned to old_init ?

Comment: @HakanBaba, no. Notice that we first save the original value of `SomeClass.__init__` into a variable named `old_init`, then we overwrite `SomeClass.__init__` with our implementation, and our implementation calls the saved `old_init` function. Infinite recursion would happen if you call `SomeClass.__init__` from the new implementation.

Answer (score 58):

Use [`mock`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) library.

```
import thirdpartymodule_a
import thirdpartymodule_b
import mock

def new_init(self):
    self.a = 43

with mock.patch.object(thirdpartymodule_a.SomeClass, '__init__', new_init):
    thirdpartymodule_b.dosomething() # -> print 43
thirdpartymodule_b.dosomething() # -> print 42
```

or

```
import thirdpartymodule_b
import mock

def new_init(self):
    self.a = 43

with mock.patch('thirdpartymodule_a.SomeClass.__init__', new_init):
    thirdpartymodule_b.dosomething()
thirdpartymodule_b.dosomething()
```

Comment: this is the only way that actually works correctly. This basically monkey-patches while you do your call, does something, and then undoes the monkey-patch. That way, other modules calling it still get the original behaviour; only you get the modified behavior. (and thanks for pointing out mock!)

Comment: @CorleyBrigman This only applies to other modules within the same process.  To me "other scripts" sounds like they would be separate Python processes that wouldn't be affected by a naive monkey-patch.

Answer (score 13):

One another possible approach, very similar to [Andrew Clark's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19546169/2267932), is to use [wrapt](http://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.
Among other useful things, this library provides `wrap_function_wrapper` and `patch_function_wrapper` helpers. They can be used like this:

```
import wrapt
import thirdpartymodule_a
import thirdpartymodule_b

@wrapt.patch_function_wrapper(thirdpartymodule_a.SomeClass, '__init__')
def new_init(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs):
    # here, wrapped is the original __init__,
    # instance is `self` instance (it is not true for classmethods though),
    # args and kwargs are tuple and dict respectively.

    # first call original init
    wrapped(*args, **kwargs)  # note it is already bound to the instance
    # and now do our changes
    instance.a = 43

thirdpartymodule_b.do_something()
```

Or sometimes you may want to use `wrap_function_wrapper` which is not a decorator but othrewise works the same way:

```
def new_init(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs):
    pass  # ...

wrapt.wrap_function_wrapper(thirdpartymodule_a.SomeClass, '__init__', new_init)
```

Answer (score 3):

Dirty, but it works :

```
class SomeClass2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 43
    def show(self):
        print self.a

import thirdpartymodule_b

# Monkey patch the class
thirdpartymodule_b.thirdpartymodule_a.SomeClass = SomeClass2

thirdpartymodule_b.dosomething()
# output 43
```

Comment: what about if i want my new class definition extend the old one (via inheritance) ?

Comment: why not inherit from `SomeClass`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example I came up with to monkeypatch `Popen` using `pytest`.

import the module:

```
# must be at module level in order to affect the test function context
from some_module import helpers
```

A `MockBytes` object:

```
class MockBytes(object):

    all_read = []
    all_write = []
    all_close = []

    def read(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # print('read', args, kwargs, dir(self))
        self.all_read.append((self, args, kwargs))

    def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # print('wrote', args, kwargs)
        self.all_write.append((self, args, kwargs))

    def close(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # print('closed', self, args, kwargs)
        self.all_close.append((self, args, kwargs))

    def get_all_mock_bytes(self):
        return self.all_read, self.all_write, self.all_close
```

A `MockPopen` factory to collect the mock popens:

```
def mock_popen_factory():
    all_popens = []

    class MockPopen(object):

        def __init__(self, args, stdout=None, stdin=None, stderr=None):
            all_popens.append(self)
            self.args = args
            self.byte_collection = MockBytes()
            self.stdin = self.byte_collection
            self.stdout = self.byte_collection
            self.stderr = self.byte_collection
            pass

    return MockPopen, all_popens
```

And an example test:

```
def test_copy_file_to_docker():
    MockPopen, all_opens = mock_popen_factory()
    helpers.Popen = MockPopen # replace builtin Popen with the MockPopen
    result = copy_file_to_docker('asdf', 'asdf')
    collected_popen = all_popens.pop()
    mock_read, mock_write, mock_close = collected_popen.byte_collection.get_all_mock_bytes()
    assert mock_read
    assert result.args == ['docker', 'cp', 'asdf', 'some_container:asdf']
```

This is the same example, but using `pytest.fixture` it overrides the builtin `Popen` class import within `helpers`:

```
@pytest.fixture
def all_popens(monkeypatch): # monkeypatch is magically injected

    all_popens = []

    class MockPopen(object):
        def __init__(self, args, stdout=None, stdin=None, stderr=None):
            all_popens.append(self)
            self.args = args
            self.byte_collection = MockBytes()
            self.stdin = self.byte_collection
            self.stdout = self.byte_collection
            self.stderr = self.byte_collection
            pass
    monkeypatch.setattr(helpers, 'Popen', MockPopen)

    return all_popens


def test_copy_file_to_docker(all_popens):    
    result = copy_file_to_docker('asdf', 'asdf')
    collected_popen = all_popens.pop()
    mock_read, mock_write, mock_close = collected_popen.byte_collection.get_all_mock_bytes()
    assert mock_read
    assert result.args == ['docker', 'cp', 'asdf', 'fastload_cont:asdf']
```

Answer (score 1):

One only slightly-less-hacky version uses global variables as parameters:

```
sentinel = False

class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        global sentinel
        if sentinel:
            <do my custom code>
        else:
            # Original code
            self.a = 42
    def show(self):
        print self.a
```

when sentinel is false, it acts exactly as before. When it's true, then you get your new behaviour. In your code, you would do:

```
import thirdpartymodule_b

thirdpartymodule_b.sentinel = True    
thirdpartymodule.dosomething()
thirdpartymodule_b.sentinel = False
```

Of course, it is fairly trivial to make this a proper fix without impacting existing code. But you have to change the other module slightly:

```
import thirdpartymodule_a
def dosomething(sentinel = False):
    sc = thirdpartymodule_a.SomeClass(sentinel)
    sc.show()
```

and pass to init:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, sentinel=False):
        if sentinel:
            <do my custom code>
        else:
            # Original code
            self.a = 42
    def show(self):
        print self.a
```

Existing code will continue to work - they will call it with no arguments, which will keep the default false value, which will keep the old behaviour. But your code now has a way to tell the whole stack on down that new behaviour is available.