# Python monkey patch a module that gets executed by another module

Tags: python

My question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545982/monkey-patching-a-class-in-another-module-in-python)

Except that it's not my module to execute `dosomething()` in `thirdpartymodule_b` so I need to  monkey patch `thirdpartymodule_a` and be effective when it's executed in `thirdpartymodule_b`

Comment: I would love for someone to tell me how this is possible if `thirdpartymodule_b` is already importing `thirdpartymodule_a`. I have never been able to do this.

Comment: You want to monkey-patch `thirdpartymodule_a` so that only `thirdpartymodule_b` uses the patched version, while other modules would still use the old one?

Comment: @warwaruk that's correct, reason for that is I want to patch a form in a thirdparty app in django, which is used by it's view.

Comment: I don't really understand. If you "patch a form in a thirdparty app in django, which is used by it's view" don't you expect that the other modules should also use the patched version?

Comment: @warwaruk yes I want the same module should also use the patch version, I think your answer guessed it, maybe the urls.py imports the class views which imports the form before my patch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any difference between the question you referenced and your situation. In both cases a modules import a name from another module and you want to patch the object referenced by that name.

In that question the module is written by the author, in your question it's a third party module.

I think your problem lies in the fact the the third party already imported the object name, so if you try to replace the object in the module where it resides, the third party module will still use the old one, because it still references the old object.

module_1.py

```
class AForm(Form):
    ...
```

module_2.py

```
from module_1 import AForm
```

If you import `module_2` and then monkey-patch `module_1` replace `AForm` with another object

```
class AFormPatched(Form):
    ...

import module_1
module_1.AForm = AFormPatched
```

Your changes will not affect `module_2`, because `module_2.AForm` still points to the original object.

To solve this:

**Option 1.** `module_2` should look like:

```
import module_1
module_1.AForm  # using AForm in this form
```

**Option 2.** Patch also `module_2.AForm`:

```
class AFormPatched(Form):
    ...

import module_1
module_1.AForm = AFormPatched
import module_2
module_2.AForm = AFormPatched
```

Or don't patch `module_1` you want only `module_2` to use the patched version.

**Option 3.** Patch attributes of the object. If you don't want to or cannot monkey patch all the places where the object name is used, sometimes it works if you don't replace the object, but patch only some of its attributes. It depends on the object and the behavior you are trying to patch:

```
import third_party_module
third_party_module.AForm.__init__ = ...
```