# How to add and serialise additional fields of an existing model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth

I'm using `django-rest-framework` and `python-social-auth` in my Django project.

Here is the serializer class of `UserSocialAuth` model in my project

```
class SocialAuthSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserSocialAuth
        fields = ('id', 'provider')
```

Then I want to an additional field `UserSocialAuth.extra_data['login']` to above Serializer, the traditional way should be

```
class UserSocialAuth(AbstractUserSocialAuth):
    def login:
        return self.extra_data['login']

class SocialAuthSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    login = serializers.CharField(source='login')
     ...

        fields = ('id', 'provider', 'login')
```

The problem is that `UserSocialAuth` is belong to `python-social-auth`, I have to change the code of `python-social-auth` app directly to add `def login:`, so how can I add the additional field to the existing model `UserSocialAuth` without touching the code of `python-social-auth`.

Comment: If I've understand you correctly, you want to add functionality to an existing class and its serializer. Why can you not write your own class `CustomUserSocialAuth(UserSocialAuth)` and implement the login method there? You could then also write a `CustomSocialAuthSerializer(SocialAuthSerializer)` that inherits the `fields` from the parent and uses the model `CustomUserSocialAuth` and add `login` to its fields accordingly.

Comment: But the `UserSocialAuth ` is used in `python-social-auth`, can I use the Serializer of subclass `CustomUserSocialAuth ` to serialise the base class `UserSocialAuth` ?

Comment: I see. In principle you can change the `UserSocialAuth` inside `python-social-auth` then. This is called Monkey-Patching, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545982/monkey-patching-a-class-in-another-module-in-python

But I would not suggest to do so. If you think the module that you use is doing wrong because it couples the serializer too tightly to the model, you should consider discussing that with the author of the module instead of monkey patching it.

Comment: I just find one way to do it without touching the raw class, thank you all the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find that I can use `SerializerMethodField` here, no need to change the raw class `UserSocialAuth`, just add one more field to the serializer like this:

```
class SocialAuthSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    login = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_login(self, obj):
        return obj.extra_data['login']
```