# Python : adding methods to a class coming from a package

Tags: python, oop

I' using a package that returns an object of class `PackageClass`.

I then use this object in several part of my code. I would like to add some attributes to this class (a method `get_processed_attr` for example that retrieves some attributes and process them the way I need them).

What would be the best way to go about it ?

I tried creating a class `CustomClass` that inherits from `PackageClass` and adds the attributes I need to it. But

1. I don't know how to create a `CustomClass` instance from a `PackageClass` instance that keeps all the attributes of `PackageClass`
2. I'm not convinced this is the best way to go about it

Comment: Have you tried to do a web search for this? And given the use case - it seems like inheritance is the answer

Comment: Simplest approach could be to 'monkey patch' the additional attribute onto the original Class object without needing Class inheritance. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545982) etc.