# Monkey patch parent of class

Tags: python-3.x

I have to following module:

```
class A():
    a = 1
class B(A):
    b = 2
```

In another file I want to replace class A ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765222/monkey-patch-python-class#3765237)):

```
import module
class C():
    c = 3
module.A = C
```

When creating a `B` object, it should inherit now from `C`, and have a `.c` attribute, however, it does not:

```
assert module.B().c == 3
```

However, this raises: `AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'c'`

How can this be fixed?

Comment: When `B` was defined, `A` was still the original `A`. `B` inherits from the class object that `A` happened to point to at the time. You can change `A`, but by then `B` is already referencing the object behind `A` not the current `A`.

Comment: Is there a solution that not requires recreating the whole module?

Comment: It would depend on what your goal is. You could just add or overwrite things on the original `A`. In your example, `module.A.c = 3`. You can do the same thing with the methods on `A`. Python looks these up dyamically, so they can be changed mid stream.

Comment: But if you are adding new things to A that existing inheritors of A don't know or care about, you may be interested in [mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful).

Answer (score 2):

Variables are references to objects. When you reassign a variable, it doesn't affect the previous object unless its reference count goes to zero and it is deleted. In your case

```
class A:
    a = 1
class B(A):
    b = 2
```

`B` gets the class object that happened to be assigned to `A` at that moment and uses that as the parent. As long as `B` uses `super` for any future reference to its parent, `B` never touches the `A` variable again. And your reassignment of `A` makes no difference.

But you did say Monkey Patch, and that is still doable. Just put stuff onto the original A class and all inheritors will see it:

```
import module
module.A.c = 3
assert module.B().c == 3
```

You can also add or replace methods

```
import module

def d(self):
    return 4

module.A.d = d
assert module.B().d() == 4
```

Alternately, if you just want this change to happen for *some* inheritors of A, consider mixins [What is a mixin, and why are they useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful)

Comment: This means that one has to add every method and attribute from C separately to A.

Comment: @Vasco - your edited change to bulk add items from one class `__dict__` to another is interesting but further than I want to go. In that case, multiple inheritance and the mixin strategy would be more my cup of tea. It would be a good alternate answer to this question, though.

Answer (score 1):

The ideas in the [post of tdelaney](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49801830/1768422) can be automatized:

```
def replace_class(oldcls, newcls):
    '''Adds/replaces the contents for oldcls with newcls, leaving 
    references to oldcls in-place. Usefull for monkey patching'''
    for key, val in newcls.__dict__.items():
        if key != '__dict__':
            setattr(oldcls, key, val)
```

Now this works

```
replace_class(module.A, C)
module.B().c == 2
```