# Monkey-patching class with inherited classes in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, monkeypatching

After reading the answers to [the question about monkey-patching classes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765222/monkey-patch-python-class) I tried to apply the advised solution to the following case.

Imagine that we have a module `a.py`

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print(1)

class AA(A):
    pass
```

and let us try to monkey patch it as follows. It works when we monkey patch class `A`:

```
>>> import a
>>> class B(object):
...     def foo(self):
...             print(3)
... 
>>> a.A = B
>>> x = a.A()
>>> x.foo()
3
```

But if we try the inherited class, it turns to be not patched:

```
>>> y = a.AA()
>>> y.foo()
1
```

Is there any way to monkey patch the class with all its inherited classes?

**EDIT**

For now, the best solution for me is as follows:

```
>>> class AB(B, a.AA):
...     pass
... 
>>> a.AA = AB
>>> x = a.AA()
>>> x.foo()
3
```

Any complex structure of `a.AA` will be inherited and the only difference between `AB` and `a.AA` will be the `foo()` method. In this way, we don't modify any internal class attributes (like `__base__` or `__dict__`). The only remaining drawback is that we need to do that for each of the inherited classes.

Is it the best way to do this?

Comment: You can use `a.A.foo = B.foo`.

Comment: @MaxiMouse Actually, I need to replace the class in a whole

Comment: Maybe `a.A.__dict__ = B.__dict__`?

Comment: `a.A.__dict__` doesn't contain `AA`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually possible because you can't change base classes dynamically. (You can get a list of subclasses using `A.__subclasses__()`.)

Comment: @IlyaPalachev After `a.A = B`, you can do `class AB(A, AA): pass ; AA = AB`.

Comment: @stovfl Thank you! This seems to be the best solution, and it works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly overwrite the tuple of base classes in `a.AA`, though I don't recommend modifying classes like this.

```
>>> import a
>>> class B:
...   def foo(self):
...     print(2)
...
>>> a.AA.__bases__ = (B,)
>>> a.AA().foo()
2
```

This will also be reflected in `a.A.__subclasses__()` (although I am not entirely sure as to *how* that works; the fact that it is a method suggests that it computes this somehow at runtime, rather than simply returning a value that was modified by the original definition of `AA`).

It *appears* that the bases classes in a `class` statement are simply remembered, rather than *used*, until some operation needs them (e.g. during attribute lookup). There may be some other subtle corner cases that aren't handled as smoothly: *caveat programmator*.

Comment: If we are going to modify each class that inherits from A, then it seems better to do as @stovfl has suggested: `class AB(A, AA): pass ; AA = AB`. Do you know which way is better?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend either approach as a general technique, without knowing more about the exact class hierarchy I am trying to patch.